# SheetJS don't parse corectly the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, export-to-excel, sheetjs

I am trying to export my html table to excel file, using SheetJS library. This is my code:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("tableToExport");
 var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(table, { sheet: "Raport Odorizare",dateNF: 'dd.mm.yyyy'});
 var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
 XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Raport Odorizare");
 XLSX.writeFile(wb, "Raport Odorizare.xlsx");
```

My date in html table look like this: "2021-08-06" (whitout the time)

However when I export to excel my date look like this: "08/06/2021  12:00:24 AM" (see the picture,pls) and I can't figured it out why my date in excel is beeing generated with the time part.

[image]

Comment: It's most likely Excel doing that. It will auto-format any dates it detects to the default for the culture your Excel runs under. You can test this by outputting the data to CSV and check what format the dates are in as text

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with another type of format (`dd/mm/yyyy`), Excel was doing some weirds conversions.

After doing some research, I was able to export these rows as raw data, meaning that Excel won't do any transformations and this data will displayed in the Excel cells as they do in the HTML table.

In your case, for the date format you are pursuing here (`yyyy-mm-dd`), this will be the JS code:

```
function export(tableId, filename) {
    let elt = document.getElementById(tableId);
    let wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet: filename, dateNF: 'yyyy-mm-dd;@', cellDates: true, raw: true});
    return XLSX.writeFile(wb, filename + '.xlsx');
}
```